# Change label value in UICollectionView without reload data?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm using swift 2.2 and i have a collectionview inside cell ia hve a label.I want to change a label text value in UICollection view on a button click without using reloading whole uiCollection view.
I can't use collectionView.reloadData() for my scenario. I want a do it without using it. Just to update one label in a particular item in collectionview.
Any help??

Comment: use reloadobjectatindex concept

Comment: you should use 'reloadItemsAtIndexPaths' method of collectionview to reload particular cell of collectionview

Comment: where are your button? in collectionviewcell ?

Comment: button is not in the cell

Comment: @Anushka Madushan If you want to manage background colour of specific cell after selection, Then you can use a selectedIndex variable. You can set the selectedIndexPath to that variable and when your uicollecionview reload so you have to provide color to that specific cell using that selectedIndex variable.

Comment: @Anushka Madushan I can explain this in better way if you want.

Answer (score 8):

If you pass the IndexPath you can access the cell, then from it you can change the label using this syntax

```
let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath) as? yourCollectionViewCellName
cell.label.text = "new text"
```

Comment: @AnushkaMadushan can you tell me what is happening when you are using this?

Comment: my collection view i have label and image(icon) and selected item should show different coloricon so if i reload data that pre selected item also reload . i want preselected item as it is and reload data in collection view

Comment: You need to cast the cell to to collectionview cell class name, I will update the answer

Comment: ok if you refresh or scroll the collection your item will be reuseable

Comment: You need to update the change in your model also else on reuse the data goes back to old one

Comment: Its not working without reload collectionview any other solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by this way:

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 0)
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
```

It will not reload your complete `UICollectionView`.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

In swift 5 you can do it with below code

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rowIndexNumber, section: sectionNumber)
 // you can update a bunch of items
collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
```